# How to create a database using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, create-table

In this `create` function, I am trying to create a database. However, it fails to create and displays the error `Error creating database: Access denied.` So, this means there is a connection and it makes it past the first check. Then when `mysql_query` is called, it doesn't return true. Can anyone help?

```
function create($dbName, $tbName, $fields, $types_sizes, $PK)
        {
            $sql = null;
            $con = mysql_connect("borg.cs.up.ac.za","username", "password");

            if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else 
                {
                  if(mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE". $dbName, $con))
                    {
                        echo "Database created";
                        $dbExists = 1;
                    }
                   else
                    {
                        echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
                        $dbExists = 0;
                    }
                   $i = 0;
                    if(($con)&&($bdExists = 1))
                    {
                        $sql . "CREATE TABLE " . $tbName . "(";
                        while($i < count($fields))
                        {
                            $sql . $fields[$i] . " " + $types_sizes[$i] . ",";
                            $i++;
                        }
                    if($PK != null)
                    {
                        $sql . "PRIMARY KEY (" . $PK .")";
                    }
                    }
                mysql_query($sql,$con);
                mysql_close($con);
            }
         }
```

Comment: You probably do not have the necessary privileges to create databases on the account you connect to the server.

Comment: Also you may set prefix ($dbName_.'tablename') in name for separate tables

Comment: Create the database using PhpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench then just create the tables via code.  It seems you do not have the required permissions to create a database.

Comment: I do have the full amount of privileges so thats not a problem.I have an idea its got something to do with the connection, and not the query.

Comment: @Chris the error message exactly telling you that you don't have the privileges. You wouldn't have got that message had it been connection issue. and `mysql_*` is deprecated officailly. You should learn `mysqli` or better `PDO`.

Comment: Please do refer this link
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp

Answer (score -1):

you have not given space in the line

`if(mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE". $dbName, $con)),` please provide space after "**Create Database**" **->** "**create database** "`.$dbname`, because otherwise it will be database+name combined.

Comment: this query didn't run in the 1st place because access was denied.

Comment: let the user run it once and then decide whether it is working or not.

Comment: OK so @Gaurav Bansal. Thanks. There was a space missing. But now its giving me this error "Error creating database: Access denied for user 's11028786'@'%' to database 'books' ", any ideas? i have to have access, because i successfully connect in my previous function.

Comment: `If you get an error such as Access denied for user 'monty'@'localhost' to database 'menagerie' when attempting to create a database, this means that your user account does not have the necessary privileges to do so.` ----- mysql dev guide.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This is untested.Changed some lines in your code.

```
function create($dbName, $tbName, $fields, $types_sizes, $PK)
    {
        $sql = null;
        $con = mysql_connect("borg.cs.up.ac.za","username", "password");

        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else 
            {
    if(mysql_select_db($dbName))
                {
                    echo "Database selected";
                    $dbExists = 1;
                }
               else
                {
                    echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
                    $dbExists = 0;
                }
               $i = 0;
                if(($con)&&($dbExists == 1))
                {
                    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $tbName . "(";
                    while($i < count($fields))
                    {
                        $sql .= $fields[$i] . " " + $types_sizes[$i] . ",";
                        $i++;
                    }
                if($PK != null)
                {
                    $sql .= "PRIMARY KEY (" . $PK .")";
                }
                }
            mysql_query($sql,$con);
            mysql_close($con);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

Easy, just follow this two steps

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");

mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
```

Comment: The question is about creating a database through code not connecting and selecting one